# Problems with FB.api() posting and sending notifications

Tags: javascript, facebook

I cant seem to make a POST request or get this function to work, but I cant seem to do it and it gave no specific error. But here is the code

```
var body = 'Hello world on post';
FB.api('/100008601850848/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured' + response.error);
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

I dont have any information to give you because the error did not give me information and FB api documentation on it is not clear

Comment: did you debug the response? put a console.log(response) at the beginning of your callback and post the exact response (of course not in comments, but in your question).

Comment: I already did and mentioned it gave no error

Comment: I already handled the error in a try{}catch(){} it gave no errror

Comment: Except I used alert and not console.log()

Comment: alert is a very bad way to debug javascript. and try/catch is pointless here. again, put console.log(response) right at the beginning of the callback function, that´s the only good way to debug it.

Comment: Error occured[object Object] - Same thing that popped up on alert()

Comment: well...debug the object then. either by using browser dev tools or with JSON.stringify.

Comment: Stop using string concatenation in your debug output. `console.log(response)` – do _that_, and then check the logged object in browser console.

Comment: Could not it gave no error